# How to provide security with Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am new with Struts2 framework. I wanted to make use of this framework. So I wanted to know how we can provide better security using Struts2 framework or how it is more secured?

Comment: You can use any security framework, or you can use principal aware actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide Security using the Interceptors. Interceptors are good way to handle possible script attack.

You can write your own custom interceptor and can implement security feature using OWASP(Open Web Application Security Project descriptions.

[http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-creating-own-interceptor/][1]

You can took a look on how to write custom interceptor.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

OWASP provide solutions for security feature like xxas attack.